# Broken Github icon on the My logins page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, github, profile-edit

I have a GitHub login. When going to [My logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) tab on the profile, I see this:

> [image: My logins, with GitHub icon broken]

As you can see, the icon for GitHub is broken. Can this please be fixed?

Comment: What is the URL of the broken icon?

Comment: @Shadow9 https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Img/openid/openid-logos.png?v=ecc2538a8df2 they all use the same image, but with an offset.

Comment: I see. So the sprites doesn't have GH icon yet. What's the offset on the icon?

Comment: @Shadow9 `.icon-github {
    background-position: 0 -114px;
}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed. The github icon on the logins page is now shown, with all of its splendor.